How to fix SSL cert error in Python request if company VPN proxy changes remote website SSL certificates
VPN proxy changes remote website SSL certificates.  There is no issues if I run without VPN.
Currently I have to set verify to false to disable the certificate validation if I run inside VPN (response = requests.get(url, verify=False)).  Is there a fix for this? Thanks!

Lots of solutions under this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi?rq=2

I've personally used this answer, this answer, and—while a different question—this answer.

Ian Thompson - I am using response = requests.get(url, verify=False).  I would like to change to response = requests.get(url, verify=True) and the validation still passes

Try the last answer I linked to.
